# setting tabindex to angular material element

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, tabindex

i have a password field created using angular material. and there is a password visibility toggle button there. if it were a simple button i could have set tabindex="-1", but tabindex doesn't work on "mat-pass-toggle-visibility"

```
                  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 100%;" class="input-custo-design">
                    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                    <mat-pass-toggle-visibility #toggle matSuffix></mat-pass-toggle-visibility>

                    <input matInput [type]="toggle.type" placeholder="Password" formControlName="pass" #passwordWithValidation />
                    <mat-error *ngIf="signupController.pass.errors?.required">Password is required
                    </mat-error>
                   
                  </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

i got a github link [mat-password](https://github.com/angular-material-extensions/password-strength/issues/255), where this issue is there, but currently is there somehow i can do a workaround??

in chrome dev-tools i can see "mat-pass-toggle-visibility" does in the end create a button only. so can we set any directive or such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for my use case i got another way around:
using the normal button class

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 100%;" class="input-custo-design">
  <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
  <input matInput [type]="hideSignUp ? 'password' : 'text'" placeholder="Password" formControlName="pass" #passwordWithValidation />
                    
  <button
   type="button"
   mat-icon-button
   matSuffix
   (click)="hideSignUp = !hideSignUp"
   [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
   [attr.aria-pressed]="hide"
   tabindex="-1"
 >
 <mat-icon>{{
   hideSignUp ? "visibility_off" : "visibility"
 }}</mat-icon>
 </button>
 <mat-error *ngIf="signupController.pass.errors?.required">Password is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ability to specify `tabindex` was added with this [pull request](https://github.com/angular-material-extensions/password-strength/pull/304).